# Can I use Google Apps Sync for Outlook purely as a sync tool and not for email migrations?

Tags: email, sync, microsoft-outlook-2010, google-workspace, google-sync

I run Outlook 2010 against Exchange and will continue to do so.  However on an ongoing basis I want to sync emails from Outlook to my Google Apps account.  Essentially I just want to sync my emails to Google Apps but I have no plans to leave Exchange.

I do the Google Apps Sync for Outlook install and then run "Set up a Google Apps Sync user" which prompts me to authenticate to my Google Apps account, asks me if I want to import emails, calendar, etc. and then makes me create a new profile.  If I import my emails at this time, they are obviously pulled from my *original* profile.  When complete, all my emails show in my new Outlook profile and in Google Apps, just like they should.  But moving forward I want to continue using Exchange which means using my original profile, and by definition this profile isn't sync'd.  So given this, how can I keep working against my Exchange-based email and sync those changes to gmail?

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish? A backup in the cloud? Something else?

Comment: I want my emails in gmail (I will access them in a read-only way) because there are some tools I want to try that work with gmail but not exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-listened to the video at https://tools.google.com/dlpage/gappssync and realized that the Google Apps Outlook Sync tool isn't meant for this.  I wanted to keep working against Exchange and simply have my emails be synced to my google apps account.  What the tool is doing is creating a new Outlook profile which points to your google apps account, then imports your emails et al from your original Exchange profile into this new profile, ie your data is now sitting in Google Apps.  Once the import is done your content is re-downloaded from google apps back to your outlook client in the new profile.  The video goes on to say that you can turn off Exchange and keep working with outlook against google apps.  So Exchange is out of the picture.