# Sync sent emails from Exchange to Gmail

Tags: sync, gmail, exchange

I would like to sync my sent items (and the draft) from Exchange to Gmail. Unfortunately I can only enable a POP3 account which sync the inbox only.

Is there a way (this could involve a third-party service) to sync my Exchange account with Gmail?

Comment: Please elaborate a bit more on the question. Who is the provider of the Exchange account? Is one of the 2 accounts a G-Suite account with Exchange used to sync email? Do you want to sync mail between two different email accounts from different email providers? Microsoft Office outlook [can do it for you](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/export-or-backup-email-contacts-and-calendar-to-an-outlook-pst-file-14252b52-3075-4e9b-be4e-ff9ef1068f91) if you want to completely transfer the emails.

Answer (score 1):

There are other users who have the same issue as you. I'm afraid that finding the correct tool for this may be problematic and you may try the other workarounds mentioned in [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/320237/can-i-sync-my-outlook-exchange-emails-to-gmail-or-google-apps-without-migrating).